# How to implement temporary edits

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In the chrome developer tools here,

[image]

You can double click and edit these properties,

After editing, if I want my chrome extension to change 'padding-left' to 16px I use this line:

```
$('.tsf-p').css('padding-left', '16px');
```

What code would I use to change the position field to inherit?

Answer (score 1):

`$('.tsf-p').css({ 'padding-left': '16px', 'position': 'inherit' });` should do it.